# Compare Hashmap values which are store as List structure

Tags: java, list, arraylist, data-structures, hashmap

I have hashmap which its key is String and values stored as List.

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> posmap = new HashMap<>();
```

Because i have multiple values under same key. 
So for example i have 4 keys and values are:

[1681, 3523]

[276, 489]

[1527, 2865]

[300]

Also i have another treeList which contains these values as sorted.What i want to do is(and asking);

```
Iterator<Integer> itr=myTreeSet.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        int check = itr.next();
        for(Object value : map2.entrySet())
        {
            //System.out.println("Value is :" + value);

        }
    }
```

I want to check itr as shown in code with my Hashmap entrySet and if equals return hashmap key.Above code returns entrySet as a array. Briefly how to check itr belong to hashmap's entrySet and belong to which key.

**I am taking map1 and map2 as parameter**

```
static void game(Map map1, Map map2, Hero h, HashSet< Integer> hash)
```

I am sorry guys. I didnt be clear i think so you confused.  i first define this maps in main func:

```
Map<String, Enemy> enemymap = new HashMap<>();
Map<String,List<Integer>> posmap = new HashMap<>();
```

And i filled them in main func as well. After fill them i sent them to my function game which in question. posmap is map2. So i point as posmap. Sorry for confusion.
Full code of func.

```
static void game(Map map1, Map map2, Hero h, HashSet< Integer> hash)
{
    TreeSet<Integer> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<>(); // For sorting min to max-for alignment
    myTreeSet.addAll(myHashset);
    System.out.println(myTreeSet);
    String start = "Micheal started travel with" + " " + h.getHealth() + " " + "HP!";
    Iterator<Integer> itr=myTreeSet.iterator();
    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        int check = itr.next();
        /* for(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map2.entrySet())
            {
                if(entry.getValue() != null && entry.getValue().contains(check))
                System.out.println("The key " + entry.getKey() + "contains the treeset value " + check);

            } -/
    }

}
```

Sending from main func as:

```
game(enemymap, posmap , hero, myHashset);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question because it's so sloppy.  Is `posmap` supposed to be the same as `map2`?  But if you want to test whether an integer is in one of the list of values in the map, you'll need to look at all the values and use something like `List.contains`.  And don't say `Object value`, say `Map.Entry<String,List<Integer>> value`.  Otherwise you won't be able to retrieve the values.

Comment: I think your clarification has made things less clear.  Also, using raw types (like `Map`, instead of `Map<String,List<Integer>>`) in your parameter list will make it difficult to write code to do the right thing, since the compiler doesn't know that your keys are strings and your values are lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend the following approach:

```
Iterator<Integer> itr=myTreeSet.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext())
{
    int check = itr.next();
    for(Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map2.entrySet())
    {
        if(entry.getValue() != null && entry.getValue().contains(check))
        System.out.println("The key " + entry.getKey() + "contains the treeset value " + check);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ajb. Appreciate your inputs. Just fixed it.

Comment: it say for  map2.entrySet: Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type  Object to Map.Entry

Comment: By the way, i am taking map2 as a parameter.

Comment: @Lucas, what s the type of `map2`? Is it not `Map<String,List<Integer>> ` as you have described in your question?

Comment: yes its is. Map<String, List <Integer>> = new HashMap();

Comment: @Lucas, you need to show your complete code. I can't see a reason why you should get that error.

Comment: @Lucas, I just saw your edits. You need to explicitly cast `map2` to `Map<String, List <Integer>>`. Your method parameters are of type `Map` not `Map<String, List <Integer>>`.

Answer (score 2):

The other solutions print or return a single key.  Based on your short original post, I thought you wanted a set, so here's what I made.

EDITED with @ajb's advice:

```
Set<Integer> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
Map<String,List<Integer>> posmap = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<Integer> itr = myTreeSet.iterator();

//The set of keys containing values in any list of posmap
Set<String> matchedKeys = new HashSet<>();

//Iterate through the TreeSet Integers
itr.forEachRemaining(itrVal -> {
   //Stream each entry of the posmap
   posmap.entrySet().stream()
         //Remove the entries without the itrVal in the entry's list
         .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(itrVal))
         //Add each key with a match to the set
         .forEach(matchedEntry -> matchedKeys.add(matchedEntry.getKey()));
});

return matchedKeys;
```

This might be a nice approach if you have Apache Commons at your disposal:

```
Set<Integer> myTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
Map<String,List<Integer>> posmap = new HashMap<>();
Iterator<Integer> itr = myTreeSet.iterator();

Set<String> matchedKeys = new HashSet<>();

List<Integer> treeSetValues = IteratorUtils.toList(itr);

treeSetValues.stream().map(val -> {
   return posmap.entrySet().stream()
         .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().contains(itrVal))
         .collect(Collectors.toSet());
});

return matchedKeys;
```

If you can't use IteratorUtils.toList(), you could use Guava and Lists.newArrayList().

Comment: When I posted this solution, I thought the posmap was being searched for values from the treelist.  However, there's suddenly now a map2 in your question?

Comment: I think using `Map.Entry` is more efficient.  Your method retrieves all the keys, and then does a lookup on each key.  When you retrieve all the keys from a map, the values should be readily available, right next to the keys.  But you're ignoring the values, and then looking them up again, which is doing double work.  Using `entrySet()` would avoid the redundant work.  Your code looks fine to me--this is just a suggestion for how it could be improved.

Comment: No no . posmap is actual value. map2 is parameter name.Answer for Matt comment.

Comment: I'll try to adjust my solution to use what you explained @ajb and repost here in a sec, thanks!

Comment: @Lucas Then why did you put in bold letters "I am taking **map1** as the parameter name"?  Now you have two map parameters and we're even more confused than before.

Comment: Hey ajb, i know u confused so i add all information. I am sorry i couldnt be clear .

Answer (score 1):

since you did not remember the hashkey you used when storing the int in the hashmap, you will need to check, if the int is in any of the values of the hash.

```
for(Map.Entry<String,List<Integer>>entry: map2.values()) {
    if( entry.getValue().contains(check) ) return entry.getKey();
}
```

something like that.